# How to uninstall mini conda? python

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation, conda, miniconda

I've install the conda package as such:

```
$ wget http://bit.ly/miniconda
$ bash miniconda
$ conda install numpy pandas scipy matplotlib scikit-learn nltk ipython-notebook seaborn
```

I want to uninstall it because it's messing up my pips and environment.

- **How do I uninstall conda totally?**
- **Will it uninstall also my pip managed packages? If so, is there a way to uninstall conda safely without uninstalling packages managed by pip?**

Comment: Most answers properly reference official docs but are outdated, since the doc page [changes](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/uninstall/) [often](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/). The most up-to-date answer lies in the docs. This is the link at the time of writing: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Answer (score 140, accepted):

In order to [uninstall miniconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/uninstall/), simply remove the `miniconda` folder,

```
rm -r ~/miniconda/
```

As for avoiding conflicts between different Python environments, you can use virtual environments. In particular, with Miniconda, the following workflow could be used,

```bash
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-3.7.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
$ bash miniconda
$ conda env remove --yes -n new_env    # remove the environement new_env if it exists (optional)
$ conda create --yes -n new_env pip numpy pandas scipy matplotlib scikit-learn nltk ipython-notebook seaborn python=2
$ activate new_env
$ # pip install modules if needed, run python scripts, etc
  # everything will be installed in the new_env
  # located in ~/miniconda/envs/new_env
$ deactivate
```

Comment: If you used `pip` to install things into the Miniconda Python then removing the Miniconda directory will also remove them. If you installed them into another Python installation then it won't.

Comment: Also remove the path export in your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Path is added in ~/.bashrc for 4.1.11

Comment: @bugmenot123 This depends on your OS. For Linux it is in ~/.bashrc while for MacOS (and presumably BSDs) it is ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: On windows use the normal way of uninstalling a program/app, but look for "Python X.X (Miniconda xxx)". See [conda docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html#).

Comment: In my case it was `rm -r ~/miniconda3/
`

Comment: On my Mac it was `rm -r ~/opt/miniconda3/` and the path export was also added to `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 119):

The proper way to **fully** uninstall conda (Anaconda / Miniconda):

1. Remove all conda-related files and directories using the Anaconda-Clean package

   ```
   conda activate your_conda_env_name
   conda install anaconda-clean
   anaconda-clean # add `--yes` to avoid being prompted to delete each one
   ```
2. Remove your entire conda directory

   ```
   rm -rf ~/miniconda3
   ```
3. Remove the line which adds the conda path to the `PATH` environment variable

   ```
   vi ~/.bashrc
   # -> Search for conda and delete the lines containing it
   # -> If you're not sure if the line belongs to conda, comment it instead of deleting it just to be safe
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
4. Remove the backup folder created by the the Anaconda-Clean package
   **NOTE: Think twice before doing this, because after that you won't be able to restore anything from your old conda installation!**

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup
   ```

Reference: [Official conda documentation](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/uninstall/)

Comment: What does anaconda-clean actually do though?

Comment: @einpoklum
Running `anaconda-clean` removes conda related material. Here's the output:

`(venv) user@HOME:~$ anaconda-clean`

`Delete .conda? (y/n): y`

`Backup directory: /home/user/.anaconda_backup/2022-04-03T203524`

`Delete .condarc? (y/n): y`

`Delete .ipython? (y/n): y`

`Delete .jupyter? (y/n): y`

Comment: `anaconda-clean` [removes files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184796/570918). The previous comment is *not* a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using windows, just search for miniconda and you'll find the folder. Go into the folder and you'll find a miniconda uninstall exe file. Run it.

Answer (score 3):

### Update Sept 2023: Uninstalling Anaconda Distribution from MacOS

#### According to [Official documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/) you need to install `anaconda-clean`

> **conda install anaconda-clean**

## 1. Run `anaconda-clean`

After installation run `anaconda-clean` to remove all Anaconda-related files and directories. It will ask for **confirmation** before deleting each file

```
# If you want to confirm each file and directory you are deleting
anaconda-clean
```

Or you can delete all files without confirmation with `--yes` argument

```
# If you don't want to be asked about each file and directory
anaconda-clean --yes
```

The `anaconda-clean` command also creates a backup of files in the home directory in a folder named `.anaconda_backup`

## 2. Delete all Conda related folder

The following are a few examples of how you may need to delete your Anaconda folder

```
rm -rf anaconda3
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3
```

## 3. Remove conda from PATH variables

if you have conda path set in `~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login`, remove it from there as well.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
nano ~/.profile
nano  ~/.zshrc
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: There is no longer a reference to `anaconda-clean` in the linked official documentation page. Based on [archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/), it was removed sometime in Oct/Nov 2023.

Comment: `anaconda-clean` is just a file remover. No one *needs* to install it to remove Conda. See [the files it cleans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184796/570918).

Answer (score 2):

your have to comment that line in ~/.bashrc:

```
#export PATH=/home/jolth/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

and run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This only stops `miniconda` from being available system-wide. This does not uninstall it. Of course, you need to remove this line after you uninstall `miniconda`, but this is *not* the only thing you must do.

Answer (score 2):

To update @Sunil answer: Under Windows, Miniconda has a regular uninstaller. Go to the menu "Settings/Apps/Apps&Features", or click the Start button, type "uninstall", then click on "Add or Remove Programs" and finally on the Miniconda uninstaller.

Comment: on my Mac (M2) Minicoda ( 4.12.0) was installed in ~/opt/miniconda/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the list of possible installations: **uninstalling standalone Mamba** (or micromamba) from **Windows** is quite straightforward. Open the software installation catalogue "Apps & Features" and look for python. It should look like this.

[image: uninstalling mamba from windows]

After hitting uninstall you are guided through the process by the uninstaller.