# conda install conda finds conflicts on fresh install

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

How do I run `conda install conda` without conflicts?

Everything I do with Anaconda now finds conflicts and fails. To try and fix this problem I did the following:

1. Uninstall current Anaconda,
2. Restart the computer,
3. Fresh install of Anaconda3-2020.11-Windows-x86_64,
4. `conda install conda`.

I already have conflicts! The list of conflicts is probably 40 pages worth of text.

Did I do a bad job of uninstalling the previous Anaconda Installation or is this now the expected behavior? Is there some way to get around this issue? I'd like to abandon Anaconda all together but a package I use can't be installed without it (rdkit).

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retry the uninstall. Make sure to remove related hidden files (see [what `anaconda-clean` deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184796/570918)). You may also want to run `conda init --reverse` before uninstalling.

Sounds like you don't need *Anaconda* at all, but really just Conda. In that case, install [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download), or some variant.

Finally, avoid compromising your **base** installation by not using it for work. Create new environments for your projects (or just to install `rdkit`).

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I did not have to do the `conda init --reverse` step. I don't work in my base installation, but after a few years it seems to accumulate a few accidental installs. I might give miniforge a try in the future. I really appreciate the help!