# How to uninstall Anaconda on OSX, I've tried the anaconda-clean but failed

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I tried to install anaconda-clean to uninstall anaconda from my macbook, but I cannot install the anaconda-clean. I've tried the conda install anaconda-clean but failed. I've already tried some other channels but still cannot find the package, as shown in follows:

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- anaconda-clean

Current channels:

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page

I cannot post more than 8 links. The channels include the 'mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn', 'mirrors.ustc.edu.cn', and as follows:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

Comment: Do you need a backup? Any particular reason you're trying to use `anaconda-clean`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use conda install to get anaconda-clean but environment fails to solve and a very slow analysis of conflicts starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166966/trying-to-use-conda-install-to-get-anaconda-clean-but-environment-fails-to-solve) That is, you don’t need to run `anaconda-clean`, just delete the same things it deletes then run the uninstaller.

Comment: Also be sure to check your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` for lines added by Conda and delete them. Alternatively, I think `conda init` has a reverse flag to undo such changes.

Comment: It sounds like your Conda might be broken, can you share the list of packages in your base environment?