# How to disassociate anaconda from VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

I used to use VScode in conjunction with anaconda, but later I started to appreciate the light weight stuff. So, I would like to uninstall anaconda. I have tried to do so using all the methods suggested in the forum, including using the designated anaconda-clean. None of them really works. This helped a little bit to the point I could successfully install the cleaner. But as I proceed to actually remove anaconda, nothing really happened.

Please see the thread attached as below.

Conda is surprisingly still there. So I figured an alternative would be to just disassociate anaconda or conda from VScode? How would you do so? Thank you!

[Trying to use conda install to get anaconda-clean but environment fails to solve and a very slow analysis of conflicts starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166966/trying-to-use-conda-install-to-get-anaconda-clean-but-environment-fails-to-solve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I butchered the anaconda in my mac. Very unelegant. I manually deleted as much of it as possible. That way VScode is freed from anaconda. I would still appreciate an elegant other than just manually removing which is a pain in the rear.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments:

- in VSCode, open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
- type "Python: Select Interpreter"
- choose another Python interpreter installed in the computer

If none is found, type "Python: Create Environment" in the same Command Palette to create a new virtual environment. If there is another python.exe in the computer, you might need to add the path to the environment variables.