# zsh: command not found: anaconda-clean but condo install worked

Tags: macos, anaconda, conda, zsh, uninstallation

so I tried to do a clean uninstall of anaconda from my MacBook Air m1.
I have followed this steps on the official site(Option B): https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

The first command worked
"conda install anaconda-clean"

The second didn't "anaconda-clean --yes"

Output: zsh: command not found: anaconda-clean

Same when trying "anaconda-clean"

Why doesn't it work? I didn't change directory and successfully installed the anaconda-clean package. How to solve it?

thanks

Comment: Try: `./anaconda-clean --yes` (in the directory where "anaconda-clean" is located

Comment: where is the location of anaconda clean?
I have a folder called "opt" which includes "anaconda3". I have tried running your command from that folder.
It says: "zsh: no such file or directory: ./anaconda-clean"

Comment: If `whereis anaconda-clean` does not work, then `find / -name anaconda-clean` should work (but take some more time).  (The results should tell you that it is in in the `anaconda3/bin` directory)

Comment: thank you, it worked from the bin directory within opt/anaconda3/bin

Comment: Sounds like the Conda **base** environment was not active.

Comment: The solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166966/trying-to-use-conda-install-to-get-anaconda-clean-but-environment-fails-to-solve) worked for me -

Answer (score 6):

You need to activate conda first:

```
conda activate
```

and then do:

```
anaconda-clean --yes
```

Comment: It didn't work. I got: `(eval):16: unmatched "`

Comment: Didn't work for me