# Uninstalling conda distribution on Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to uninstall the conda distribution on my Mac using the following standard commands:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean -yes
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

To address the above error I try:

```
conda update conda
```

Or:

```
conda update --force conda
```

Which in turn returns:

```
CondaVerificationError: The package for matplotlib-inline located at appears to be corrupted. The path specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall Anaconda completely from macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos)

Comment: I believe the `rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup` requires a timestamp.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm trying these exact same steps but keep getting stuck with the CondaVerificationError.

Comment: It seems that by the error, it can't find certain packages.  Does [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41732/conda-verification-failed) help?

Comment: I'm confused: you remove anaconda, then you execute the `conda` command.

Comment: At what point do you get the RemoveError error? There are four commands you executed before that; which one is giving that error? Surely not the last two (`rm`) commands?

Comment: FYI: `anaconda-clean` is just a glorified file deletion script - you can simply remove things manually (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184796/570918). The only other extra step that Anaconda docs don't mention is cleaning up your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.zshrc` file(s). Edit those to remove any "conda initialization" sections.