# How to *completely* remove conda from my Mac

Tags: macos, conda, uninstallation

Everywhere I look the suggestions seem to focus on removing Anaconda using commands:

```
sudo conda install anaconda-clean
sudo anaconda-clean --yes
```

After running this, when I type "conda" in the terminal, I still get a bunch of info about the conda package. It still exists on my computer. When I type "conda" I want my Mac to return: "zsh: command not found: conda"

I want my Mac to have *zero* knowledge that conda or anaconda ever existed on my computer.

The above commands to delete anaconda seem to work since when I type "anaconda-navigator", I get the "command not found" response as desired.

Another option I have found is to run

```
conda uninstall
```

But this gives me an error: "CondaValueError: no package names supplied".

For reference I am running 2019 MacBrook Pro (Intel) with BigSur 11.7.8.

Any help is appreciated.

Additional information:

```
type conda
```

returns

```
conda is a shell function from /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

And

```
conda info
```

returns

```
active environment : base
    active env location : /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/[USERNAME]/.condarc
 populated config files : /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.9.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest  (read only)
           channel URLs : file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel/osx-64
                          file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/pkgs
                          /Users/[USERNAME]/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/[USERNAME]/.conda/envs
                          /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.7.9 Darwin/20.6.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: If you run `type conda` in Terminal, it will tell you exactly which conda and where it is running from. If it is `/opt/homebrew/bin/conda` you can remove it with `brew rm conda`. If it is somewhere else, edit that into your question - then we'll know how you installed it which is the key to removing it.

Comment: `conda uninstall` is used to remove any package using `conda`, not to uninstall/remove `anaconda`.

Comment: In addition to what Mark suggested you'll want to simply remove the directory containing the base conda environment and any conda environments you have created. For example `rm -rf ~/anaconda3`. Running `conda info` will tell you the path. You may also have a Conda RC script that should be removed: `rm ~/.condarc`.

Comment: `anaconda-clean` just [deletes some user-level files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184796/570918). You would also need to clean up the shell init file (e.g., `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.zshrc`) to remove any Conda sections. The issue here looks like the Conda is coming from Intel's oneAPI - so that's what you need to uninstall. The directory (`/opt/intel/oneapi/`) matches [the default one their installer uses](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/installation-guide-macos/2023-2/install-with-gui.html#GUID-762602CF-7237-4335-89B9-EB9D301080DE).

Comment: The uninstallation instructions are here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/installation-guide-macos/2023-2/uninstall-oneapi-toolkits-and-components.html