# I have both Anaconda & Miniconda installed - can I delete one?

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda, anaconda3

My computer memory is nearly out of space, and in going through large packages to clean space I realized that I have miniconda3, taking up 5.71GB, and anaconda3, taking up 4.13GB. I probably did this a few years ago while mindlessly following install instructions for a class. At this point, I understand the merits/drawbacks of each distribution if I were to choose now which one I'd like to install, but I am not sure what exactly would happen if I delete one of these. Any pointers/advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you based on? also, which one do you want to remove? [Directions for Uninstalling anaconda3](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/)

Comment: I'm on Mac, and I want to remove whichever will cause fewer problems at this point, lol

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

## Uninstall anaconda3

macOS:

#### 1.

Open the macOS Terminal.app or iTerm2 terminal application, and then remove your entire Anaconda directory, which has a name such as `anaconda2`, `anaconda3`, or `~/opt`. Enter `rm -rf ~/anaconda3` to remove the directory.

#### OR:

Install the Anaconda-Clean package from Anaconda Prompt (terminal on Linux or macOS):

`conda install anaconda-clean`
In the same window, run one of these commands:

Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories with a confirmation prompt before deleting each one:

`anaconda-clean`
Or, remove all Anaconda-related files and directories without being prompted to delete each one:

`anaconda-clean --yes`
Anaconda-Clean creates a backup of all files and directories that might be removed in a folder named .anaconda_backup in your home directory. Also note that Anaconda-Clean leaves your data files in the AnacondaProjects directory untouched. After that has been done, go ahead and do option 1.

## Uninstall minconda

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616442/13609047) by [rth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791279/rth):
In order to uninstall miniconda, simply remove the miniconda folder,

```
rm -rf ~/miniconda/
```

> ### Note: You can use the same directions as anaconda to uninstall miniconda

## Removing Anaconda/miniconda path from .bash_profile

If you use Linux or macOS, you may also wish to check the .bash_profile file in your home directory for a line such as:

```
export PATH="/Users/jsmith/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
# replace that with your path to anaconda
```

Comment: FYI I needed to add the `f`  flag to  run successfully:  `rm -rf ~/miniconda3/`

Answer (score 0):

You can export the environment variables before delete any one of them. Export the environment variables allows you to restore the environment in case you need it.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html