# I installed both anaconda and miniconda on a fresh Ubuntu installation. Should I expect to run into problems?

Tags: python, r, keras, conda

I installed a dual boot of Ubuntu because I wanted to work through Deep Learning with R and doing so on Windows was a pain at the installation step. I installed Anaconda (I am not a Python user but I figured I needed to install it anyway). Then, I installed Miniconda because when I ran `install.packages(keras)` in R, it asked me if I wanted to, and I just wanted Keras to be happy. Then, I followed the instructions here ([I have both Anaconda & Miniconda installed - can I delete one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887764/i-have-both-anaconda-miniconda-installed-can-i-delete-one)) to delete Anaconda but that didn't seem to do anything.

Should I just reformat my hard drive now and reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, dual booting should cause any problems. The only reason you may run into issues is if you fully run out of space.

[EDIT]: To uninstall anaconda, enter its directory and run `rm -rf ~/anaconda`, as shown [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/).

Comment: I have a 1TB dedicated SSD for Ubuntu

Comment: @CelineDion Then any issues you have are unrelated to the dual boot.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, though. I installed both Anaconda and Miniconda. I then tried to uninstall Anaconda using `anaconda-clean` and it didn't work. I'm probably being anxious.

Comment: @CelineDion That is not how you uninstall anaconda. You uninstall anaconda by entering its directory and running `rm -rf ~/anaconda`, as seen [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/)

Comment: Should I expect any problems having both Miniconda and Anaconda installed on my system? I am not familiar with these package managers.

Comment: @CelineDion I don't understand why Keras would want miniconda, given anaconda has everything miniconda has plus many more packages. You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda) thread.

Comment: @CelineDion You should avoid having both in the same conda environment.